# user input in default constructor eclipse project

Tags: c++, eclipse

this is my class in eclipse IDE C/C++ 
IRSender.h:

```
#ifndef IRSender_h
#define IRSender_h

#include <stdint.h>

class IRSender
{
  public:
    IRSender(uint8_t pin); // Cannot create generic IRSender instances
    virtual ~IRSender(){};
  public:
    virtual void setFrequency(int frequency);
    void sendIRbyte(uint8_t sendByte, int bitMarkLength, int zeroSpaceLength, int oneSpaceLength);
    uint8_t bitReverse(uint8_t x);
    virtual void space(int spaceLength);
    virtual void mark(int markLength);

  public:
    uint8_t _pin;
    uint8_t pin1;
};


class IRSenderPWM : public IRSender
{
  public:
    IRSenderPWM(uint8_t pin);
    void setFrequency(int frequency);
    void space(int spaceLength);
    void mark(int markLength);
};
```

IRSenderPWM(uint8_t pin); doesn't have body definition 
IRSender.cpp:

```
#include "IRSender.h"

// The generic functions of the abstract IRSender class

IRSender::IRSender(uint8_t pin)
{
  _pin = pin;
}

// Send a uint8_t (8 bits) over IR
void IRSender::sendIRbyte(uint8_t sendByte, int bitMarkLength, int zeroSpaceLength, int oneSpaceLength)
{
  for (int i=0; i<8 ; i++)
  {
    if (sendByte & 0x01)
    {
      mark(bitMarkLength);
      space(oneSpaceLength);
    }
    else
    {
      mark(bitMarkLength);
      space(zeroSpaceLength);
    }

    sendByte >>= 1;
  }
}


// The Carrier IR protocol has the bits in a reverse order (compared to the other heatpumps)
// See http://www.nrtm.org/index.php/2013/07/25/reverse-bits-in-a-uint8_t/
uint8_t IRSender::bitReverse(uint8_t x)
{
  //          01010101  |         10101010
  x = ((x >> 1) & 0x55) | ((x << 1) & 0xaa);
  //          00110011  |         11001100
  x = ((x >> 2) & 0x33) | ((x << 2) & 0xcc);
  //          00001111  |         11110000
  x = ((x >> 4) & 0x0f) | ((x << 4) & 0xf0);
  return x;
}


// Definitions of virtual functions
void IRSender::setFrequency(int) {};
void IRSender::space(int) {};
void IRSender::mark(int) {};
```

when I want to call constructor IRSenderPWM in main I get this error :
make: *** [main] Error 1

main:

```
#include "IRSender.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char** argc) {
     uint8_t pin =9;
    //IRSenderPWM irSender=IRSenderPWM(9);
    IRSenderPWM irSender(pin);  //this line make an error

return 0;
}
```

why I can't define and use constructor like this,I also add -std=c++11 in properties>c/c++ build>setting>tool setting>GCC c++ compiler>miscellaneous but not make different, what should I do to fix this error?

Comment: If you don't have a  definition of `IRSenderPWM::IRSenderPWM(uint8_t)`, you should expect a link time error. Why is that surprising?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append below code in your IRSender.cpp, then you can pass the build.

```
IRSenderPWM::IRSenderPWM(uint8_t pin)
    :IRSender(pin)
{
}


void IRSenderPWM::setFrequency(int frequency)

{

}


void IRSenderPWM::space(int spaceLength)

{

}


void IRSenderPWM::mark(int markLength)

{

}
```

Because you delared IRSenderPWM object in main, you have to implement its constructor, otherwise it won't work, it's from the c++ standard